# Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a website which contains a createuserwizard control. And upon creating an account, verification email along with its verify URL would be send to the user's email address.

However, when i have a test-run, upon clicking the URL in the email, this error appear:

```
Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).


Source Error: 

Line 17:         {
Line 18:             //store the user id
*Line 19:             Guid userId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["ID"]);*
Line 20: 
Error appeared on LINE 19.
```

Another funny thing is, the verification URL in my test-run look weird :

```
http://localhost:4635/WebSite2/Verify.aspx?ID=System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal
```

Normally, the URL should like this(which is a whole lot of characters at the end of the URL:

```
http://localhost:2180/LoginPage/EmailConfirmation.aspx?ID=204696d6-0255-41a7-bb0f-4d7851bf7200
```

I was actually thinking that, it there a connection with the end of the URL with my problem of the error (Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes)..

The code that generates the URL is as follows:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail(object sender,MailMessageEventArgs e)
{ 
    string domainName = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath; 
    string confirmationPage = "/Verify.aspx?ID=" + User.ToString(); 
    string url = domainName + confirmationPage; 
    e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VerificationUrl%>", url); 
}
```

Please give me suggestions and what I should do to solve this problems.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail(object sender,MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser userInfo = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName);
    Guid userInfoId = (Guid)userInfo.ProviderUserKey;

    string domainName = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;
    string confirmationPage = "/Verify.aspx?ID=" + userInfo.ToString();
    string url = domainName + confirmationPage;

    e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VerificationUrl%>", url);

}
```

Now my URL Link look like this :

```
http://localhost:4635/WebSite2/Verify.aspx?ID=username
```

But the error "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" still remained

Comment: How about showing us the code that generates the link? That's clearly where the problem lies.

Comment: this is the code for generating the URL : protected void CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail(object sender,MailMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        //MembershipUser userInfo = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName);
        //Guid userInfoId = (Guid)userInfo.ProviderUserKey;

        string domainName = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;
        string confirmationPage = "/Verify.aspx?ID=" + User.ToString();
        string url = domainName + confirmationPage;

        e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VerificationUrl%>", url);

      
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a line that says:

```
Guid userInfoId = (Guid)userInfo.ProviderUserKey;
```

Surely this is what you should provide in the URL?

```
string confirmationPage = "/Verify.aspx?ID=" + userInfoId.ToString();
```

Comment: Yeah, this line is the back of the URL

Comment: Yes, but my version is different to yours. I've used `userInfoId.ToString()`. You've used `userInfo.ToString()`

Comment: You are right, I changed it to userInfoId, and it solved the error! thanks (:

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the ID as:

```
User.ToString()
```

This resolves to the string:

```
"System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal"
```

I don't see a GUID anywhere, so it's anyone's guess as to how you want to generate this.

Comment: Where should I place this "System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal"? as a namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing ID which is in your case GUID, You are trying to pass ID `value=User.Tostring().`

Answer (score 0):

You should make two changes. Firstly, as mentioned `User.ToString()` will always produce `"System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal"`. You should change this to:

```
User.Guid.ToString()
```

Secondly, your web page should code more defensively and use TryParse as in:

```
  Guid g;
  if (Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"], out g))
    // its a good Guid
  else
    // its not a valid Guid
```