# C# with MySQL - Error: "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes" when trying to open the connection

Tags: c#, mysql, guid

Im developed a software and it's now time to test it connection to a online server.
Im developing in C# using Visual Studio and I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server. To be specifc Im trying to connect to a test server at db4free server.
I changed my ConnectionString to:

```
connectionString = "SERVER=db4free.net;PORT=3306;DATABASE=prpsystem;UID=database;PWD=password;";
```

But when I try to open the connection to check if the login is OK the visual studio shows this message error:

Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes.

Do you guys know what is happening? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to run `mysql check table`  https://logicalread.com/check-repair-mysql-tables-mc13/#.W-RDmpNKhaQ

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lBsFAkM
Here is. Bradley

Comment: @BradleyGrainger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224493/guid-should-contain-32-digits-with-4-dashes)

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Not a duplicate of that question; see the call stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash is coming from `Driver.LoadCharacterSets`, which is [executing `SHOW COLLATION`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/edafe8d93140949ab1f4a4ee00f9871c4fb04e8a/MySQL.Data/src/Driver.cs#L333). This is [bug 92982](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92982) that has been reported against the Connector/NET driver.

According to the OP on that case, he fixed the problem by disabling the `skip-character-set-client-handshake` setting in his my.cnf for MySQL Server. If you also have that setting, try disabling it to see if it resolves the problem.

Otherwise, you could switch to [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/), an alternate ADO.NET library for MySQL, which doesn't have this bug.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you soo much. The MySqlConnector from the NuGet Galeery works fine.

Comment: I solved this issue with db4free and the MySql.Data nuget package by adding OldGuids=True; to the connection string

Comment: @noontz Just be aware that with `OldGuids=true`, any `BINARY(16)` column will be returned as a `Guid` rather than `byte[]`, which can be surprising behaviour.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Thx for the warning..  I had no idea about this. It was a try and error approach that lead me to the proposed fix